# Is a heavy bag and walking enough to lose large amounts of weight

Tags: weight-loss

So I have recently gotten a heavy bag from a friend who was selling one. It’s not the heaviest of bags it’s 70 pounds.

I have never done any boxing or any real working out but ever since covid started I have gained a lot of weight. I’m 6’5 and around 340 pounds. At 225 I was skinny enough to see my ribs if that helps visualize my body type.

I want to lose at least 90-100 pounds and want to know if a heavy bag routine mixed with some cardio could achieve these goals or if I should seek other options. I have read a lot of mixed opinions on this so I’m just wondering if there’s any success story’s or someone with a better option.

Of course I know diet is a huge thing that is already being changed but I don’t get much exercise through work or any normal daily routine.

Answer (score 5):

**Short Answer**

*If you're in a caloric deficit you will lose weight.*

Any type of exercise that gets **your heart rate up** for a length of time will help you burn more calories and bring you closer to that deficit.
Boxing can be a fantastic form of cardio.

**It's all what you put into it.**

On that note, if you are inexperienced I highly recommend following a clear program. Do some youtubing and find a "Begginner at home Boxing workout" video to get yourself started.
It's unlikely that you just messing around with a boxing bag will bring as good results as a program.

*Following a program will also help with longevity* keeping you working out past the initial motivation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122721/discussion-on-answer-by-chuck-is-a-heavy-bag-and-walking-enough-to-lose-large-am).